# Class method changing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kind of new to python and I am facing a lot of trouble because for some reason this value within my class method is updating by it self even though I didn't touch it. I can't even make it constant... Here is the relevant piece of code that does it.

the method that is called:

```
def swapping(self,pos,puzzle):

    print('Old puzzle \n',puzzle)
    # Getting Zero point index 
    zero = obj.null_pos(puzzle)  

    # Getting Index of varied position
    var = puzzle[pos[0]][pos[1]]

    #Swappping values
    puzzle[zero[0,0],zero[0,1]] = var
    puzzle[pos[0], pos[1]] = 0
    new_puzzle = puzzle

    print('New_puzzle \n',new_puzzle)
    return new_puzzle 

# The code has been snipped into relevant parts only
for i in range(len(child_node)):
        # Check the hn of each node
        print(child_node[i])
        #where it occurs:
        num_mispl = obj.misplaced_tiles(nod.swapping(child_node[i],new_puz))
# <-- new_puz #value changes and i didn't assign it to anything
        temp_stor.append(num_mispl)
```

Comment: Where's that `class`?

Comment: Is there a difference between `puzzle[…][…]` and `puzzle[…, …]`?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `new_puzzle = puzzle` to do?

Comment: new_puzzle = puzzle is for compilation of changes.... and  the issue is that new_puz is changing for some reason while i just want it to remain the same

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compilation of changes", but are you aware that `new_puzzle = puzzle` does not make a copy of `puzzle`?

Comment: What do you mean by "compilation of changes"? And even if that statement did make a copy (it doesn't), surely you would want to apply the changes on the new puzzle?

Comment: yea i know it just assigns new puzzle to puzzle and it doesn't make a copy... the problem is in the for loop below in new_puz when i call the method of this class the next time it runs it uses the updated puzzle map and i want to use the old puzzle

Comment: So... make a copy then?

Comment: @timgeb Thanks i put a deepcopy so that it changes the trash one and it worked